# how to serve html files in nginx without showing the extension in this alias setup

Tags: html, nginx, alias

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up this alias inside nginx to display my website correctly.

The website I'm concerned with should be accessible from `mywebsite.com/mr` and is different from the site located at `mywebsite.com/`. The website is located at `/fullpath` (shortened for simplicity) The site needs to serve three kinds of content:

1. The index file located in `/fullpath/index.html`.
2. Other html files (without showing the `.html` extension in the browser).
3. Static assets (js/css/img) located in `/fullpath` and subdirectories.

I've tried changing around the order of matches in the `try_files` and found situations where they all worked, just not at the same time:

```
location /mr {
  default_type "text/html";
  alias /fullpath;

  # with this one 1 and 3 work
  # try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri; 

  # with this one 2 and 3 work
  # try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html;

  # with this one 1 and 2 work
  try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri;
}
```

When one doesn't work it 404's. Does anybody know how I can serve all kinds of files correctly?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Apparently alias and try_files [don't work together](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). However, I don't think you need to use alias.

```
location /mr {
  default_type "text/html";
  try_files  /fullpath/$uri /fullpath/$uri.html /fullpath/$uri/index.html  /fullpath/index.html;
}
```

Which would try:

- Exact file.
- File with .html added.
- Index in the path.
- Default index.

I think the root directive does work with try files but am unable to test.

```
server{
    location /mr {

        root /home/mysite/fullpath;

        default_type "text/html";
        try_files  $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Following the bottom example is changing 404 errors into 500 errors, the error logs shows `*20172 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "index.html", client:` , I ha to follow the steps shown in https://serverfault.com/questions/660986/nginx-request-files-without-extension to fix this 500 error

Answer (score 18):

I used a combo of what @Danack posted which led me to the result I was looking for (serve the html file directly):

```
location /health-check {
    default_type "text/html";
    alias /path/to/my/file.html;
}
```