# Serving static HTML files in Nginx without extension in url

Tags: nginx, webserver, httpserver

root directory = /srv/myproject/xyz/main/

in the "main" folder I have few *.html files and I want all of them to point at a url say `/test/` (which is quite different from the directory structure)

this is my very basic nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen                80;
    error_log   /var/log/testc.error.log;

    location /test/ {
         root   /srv/myproject/xyz/main/;
         #alias /srv/myproject/xyz/main/;
         default_type   "text/html";
         try_files  $uri.html ;
    }
}
```

If I use simple alias

```
location /test/ {
       alias /srv/myproject/xyz/main/;   
}
```

then its work perfectly, I mean I can access those html files by `http://www.myurl.com/test/firstfile.html` and so on

but I dont want that html extension.

I tried to follow these threads but no success
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,201491,201494

[How to remove both .php and .html extensions from url using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx)

[how to serve html files in nginx without showing the extension in this alias setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451191/how-to-serve-html-files-in-nginx-without-showing-the-extension-in-this-alias-set)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
    alias /srv/myproject/xyz/main/;
    try_files $1.html =404;
}
```

Comment: What about URLs with trailing slash?