# NGINX only serves php files

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

So I was messing around on my Ubuntu server, and now the only files that can be served are .php ones. Anything else results in a 502 Bad Gateway Error. I am running NGINX and PHP5-fpm. Any ideas what could be going wrong? I have not messed with any conf files, so I think this may be a permissions or ownership problem. I am an amateur at this stuff, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it going via the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file?

Comment: Yes. It was serving everything fine, including the php files. Now it will only serve the php files. @Darren

Comment: Edit your question and supply that code

Answer (score 0):

in your config file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/whatever.conf
there has to be server section so include index.html there (add only the relevant):

```
server {
    root /your_root_dir;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the index section was included. It was serving everything fine, until I did some permission changes on a php file - it would not let me edit it - and now it will only serve php files. Very strange.

Comment: It looks like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451191/how-to-serve-html-files-in-nginx-without-showing-the-extension-in-this-alias-set there are few approaches to do this