# Cloudflare page rules to serve static files without extension

Tags: node.js, nginx, cloudflare

I have managed to configure my Nginx (on top of Nodejs) to serve static files without the html extension (e.g. going to `site.com/about` serves the `about.html` page) - with help from these past questions: [how to serve html files in nginx without showing the extension in this alias setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451191/how-to-serve-html-files-in-nginx-without-showing-the-extension-in-this-alias-set) and https://serverfault.com/questions/346994/hide-html-file-extensions-using-nginx-rewrites

But I am unable to figure out how to set up Cloudflare page rules to work with this setup (the current page rules are setup to include static html files as well as js, css, etc.).

How do I configure cloudflare to serve the `about.html` page when the user goes to `site.com/about`, and also serve the `team.html` page when the user goes to `site.com/about/team`? Do I need to do anything special, or is the Nginx setup sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CloudFlare caching of your static pages isn't required, there's no need for you do do anything, everything should work out of the box.

If you want CloudFlare to also cache those static pages, try setting up page rules to Cache Everything on your site:

- Domain > Page Rules
- Pattern: *site.com/*
- Custom Caching > Cache everything

Once you setup the page rules, CloudFlare should cache your static pages and site.com/page1 should work. To clarify, your server is still serving the pages, not CloudFlare. **With the page rules, you are simply instructing CF to cache what your server sends for site.com/page1**, as opposed to fetching the page from your server for every visitor.

You can then add other Page Rules with higher priorities should you want to exclude certain endpoints from caching (e.g. an admin section). You won't need to do this if you're just hosting static HTML.

If this doesn't work, or if you need more control over what's being cached, check [this CloudFlare support doc](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-) for more options.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks; I do need CloudFlare to cache the static html content. My question is basically about serving the right pages when the extension at the end is not specified. As mentioned in the last paragraph in the question, when the user requests site.com/page1 (and not site.com/page1.html) CloudFlare should actually serve page1.html. Is this also going to happen when I set up the page rules as suggested above?

Comment: Once you setup the page rules, CloudFlare should cache your static pages and site.com/page1 should work. To clarify, your server is still serving the pages, not CloudFlare. With the page rules, you are simply instructing CF to cache the what your server sends for  site.com/page1, as opposed to fetching the page from your server for every visitor