# What is the right way to create url and filename for human readable url?

Tags: html, url

Question **is not** about how to get `example.com/?abcd` into  `example.com/blog/post`.

Suppose you need a file to be served at `example.com/blog/post`

(yes) Is it possible to serve html file with name **post** and get a properly rendered html page at `/post`?

If it is not possible then file should be called post.html, in that case should the href point to `/post.html` or `/post` given that in the end user should see only `/post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding '.html' at the end is neither harmful nor beneficial.

Adding '.html':

1. The browser knows how to render and there is less discrepancy.
2. The pages are easily identified.
3. It has been like this for quite some time so a lot of websites use this.

Not adding '.html':

1. More readable and user-friendly url.
2. It gives a directory like view which is easier to maintain for large websites.
3. Shorter urls usually get to higher search results.

At the end it's your choice.

Comment: I dont understand how to serve file without extension on nginx so that it would be rendered as html, it asks if I want to download file instead of showing it.

Comment: check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451191/how-to-serve-html-files-in-nginx-without-showing-the-extension-in-this-alias-set

Comment: Yes, default_type html; worked exactly like I wanted.